# Facebook login in Android App without Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I want only Facebook login feature in my Android App and don't want any other feature from Facebook SDK, so is it possible to do FB login without its SDK so that I can shrink the App size.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i dont have that much idea but you check this manually build login by facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: You should run proguard with the Facebook SDK, most of the unused code should be stripped out.